# Zen Coding worng abbreviations in Aptana

Tags: aptana, emmet

Hello I am using Zen Coding in Aptana, but some abbreviations are not working correctly.
When I type w TAB I get white-space:  instead of width:
Can someone tell me how I can set up correct abbreviations?

Comment: Haven't used Zen Coding, but you can add or edit Snippets like this: http://web-kreation.com/tutorials/create-code-snippets-in-aptana-to-improve-productivity/ And you can edit your bundles (like Zen Coding?) like this http://thomas.deuling.org/2011/09/best-way-to-add-or-edit-code-snippets-and-templates-in-aptana-studio-3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aptanas’ Tab key handler takes precedence over Zen Codings’ one (btw, Zen Coding was renamed to Emmet recently: https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-eclipse).

So in your case, you’re actually expanding Aptana snippet, not Emmet one.

You should either remove all Aptana snippets to allow Emmet to handle them or configure (via Preferences > Keys) and use another shortcut to explicitly expand Emmet abbreviations.